# Novatel GPS Smart6 with ROS

Tags: gps

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi to all,

I have a novatel GPS system composed by a [Smart6](http://www.novatel.com/products/smart-antennas/smart6/) base station and a rover station capable to provide sub-inch accuracy.
I would like to mount the rover station on my wheeled robot and record GPS data in order to use these data for [navsat_odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/navsat_odometry) and [robot_localization](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/robot_localization/html/navsat_transform_node.html).

What I need to do in order to read and record data coming from my smart6 rover station?
The [novatel_span_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/novatel_span_driver) is the only packet I need to read data from my novatel device?
It describes a connection on the ethernet port, but the smart6 device only provides a *serial interface*.

Can you help me, please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248769/novatel-gps-smart6-with-ros/) by [Marcus Barnet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5421/marcus-barnet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2016-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realize this question is pretty old, but in case you're still working on it or somebody else finds this, you might try [novatel_gps_driver](https://github.com/swri-robotics/novatel_gps_driver), which I just recently released.  I haven't tested it specifically with a Smart6, but it looks like it should use the same command set as the OEM6 device family, so I expect it will work.

---

Originally posted by [preed](https://answers.ros.org/users/30363/preed/) with karma: 88 on 2017-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1